# I couldn't push the object person to an array that is stored in local storage, the erorr is (Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push'))

Tags: javascript

```
<p class="center" >
        name:<br> <input type="text" id="nameinput" required><br>
        email:<br><input type="email" id="emailinput" required><br>
        password:<br><input type="password" id="passwordinput" required><br>
        <button id="registerbutton" onclick="co`enter code here`ntainsObject()">Register<button>
    <p><br><p id="feedback"></p><br>
    <button onclick="clearStorage()">Clear Storage</button>
   
     <body id="body">
        <script>
            var userArray = [];
            var person = {};
            var newemail;
            var oldemail;
            var feedback = document.getElementById("feedback");
            person.name = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
            person.email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
            person.password = document.getElementById("passwordinput").value;
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userArray));
            
            function containsObject(newemail, userArray) {
                newemail = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
            
                oldemail = localStorage.email;
            
                if (newemail === oldemail) {
                    feedback.innerHTML = "email exist";
                } else {
                    storeName();
                }
            }
            
            
            function storeName(person, userArray) {
            
            
                let newarray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(userArray));
                newarray.push(person);
                userArray = newarray;
                localStorage.setItem("person", JSON.stringify(userArray));
                console.log(userArray);
            }
```

Comment: So what if your localStorage item doesn't exist yet? Then it won't be an array but `null`, and the method `null.push` doesn't exist, hence the error. You should check for that and initialize it with an empty array in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mohammed when using the local storage you always must first initialize a value before altering it. Here an example :
Initializing :

```js
  localStorage.setItem('user1', 'Mohammed');
```

Then you can query the local storage to retrieve the value :

```js
localStorage.getItem('user1')
```

Or you can overwrite its value :

```js
localStorage.setItem('user1','Jip')
```

Important to know is that both the key and its assigned value must be strings. So when you want to store and initialize an array of users the array must be stored as a string. To repeat the process for your use case :
Initializing :

```js
localStorage.setItem('users',"[]")
```

Reading :

```js
localStorage.getItem('users')
```

Altering its value :

```js
let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))
users.push('Jip')
users = JSON.stringify(users)
localStorage.setItem('users',users)
```

I hope this is what you needed.